# using cd command to navigate through Program x86 and some pathing problems

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get into a file using

```
cd Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine
```

starting from the C:// folder.

I tried googling around and I keep getting things along the lines of

```
${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}
```

or to use a dir command. But it doesn't lead me to google_appengine. It just displays my file. I'm pretty sure I just don't know what words to google since I'm new and wondering if someone could help me.

Comment: `cd "Program Files (x86)\..."`.you need quotes around it, to tell the shell that the spaces are part of the path name. otherwise it'll be `cd Program` (which doesn't exist), and some extra/garbage arguments `Files`, `(x86)`, etc...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *get into a file*?

Comment: ahh thanks I read that I needed quotes or brackets but I thought it was only around 'program files' so it wasn't working

Comment: `cd ${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\google_appengine` would probably work fine as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell uses the `Tab` key for directory completion. So if you type

```
cd C:\Program
```

Then press `Tab` key to cycle through names, you will see how PowerShell adds quote marks around the directory name. If you don't quote the directory name, the `cd` command (which is an alias for `Set-Location`) won't know that the arguments after the command are a single path name. The quotes tell PowerShell that the stuff in between the quotes is a single argument instead of multiple arguments.

Comment: thanks that tab key function is very helpful. I'm probably going to use it more in the future